# What is `${1- hour}`?

Tags: date, coreutils

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/27595805/156458

```
date -d "next ${1- hour}" '+%H:00:00'
```

What is `${1- hour}`? Is it some shell parameter expansion, or  input format of date and time?

Why does `${1 hour}` not work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a parameter expansion, expanding to the text `hour` if the first positional parameter is unset. Had the expansion been `${1:- hour}`, then it would have expanded to `hour` also if the first positional parameter was empty (but set).

The code in the StackOverflow answer that you are linking to expects the first positional parameter to be something like `day` or `week`, but defaults to `hour` using this expansion if the argument is not provided.