# Meaning of dash in variable assignment

Tags: bash, shell-script

In a script they set `SEED` as

```
SEED=${4-20}
```

When I `echo $SEED` it's 20, so I wonder what is the usage of 4 here?

Comment: See [What is `${1- hour}`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/459181/what-is-1-hour) and this closely related Q [Using "${a:-b}" for variable assignment in scripts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/122845/using-a-b-for-variable-assignment-in-scripts)

Comment: @JimL. Thanks, so it means the input parameter $4 (if set), otherwise default 10.